# Description linearized tanks

Tags: mathematical-physics, control-theory, linearization

Description linearized tanks
I have a task to complete with the following content:
Given a system of two conical tanks connected in a cascade, H1=15m , D1=5m, H2=10m, D2=7m and the free outflow is specified  $ F_{iwy}=\alpha_i \sqrt{h_i} $ (h is current water level in n-tank) with the maximum values of these outflows being equal to respectively $F_{1wy_{max}} = 0.02\text{ mm}^3/\text{s} $ and $F_{2wy_{max}} = 0.015\text{ m}^3/\text{s}$ .Find the linearized description $\begin{align*}X &= AX+BU\end{align*}$ $\begin{align*}Y&=CX + DU\end{align*}$ selecting as state variables the instantaneous values of h1 and h2, y=F2wy and control F1 with initial state H10 = 10m and H20 corresponding to stable operating point(h10,h20,F2wy0).
I know that in order to find a linearized description, I need to create the equations of state for the system and determine the matrix. My idea for the matrix is as follows:
$\frac{d}{dt} h_{10}$
$\frac{d}{dt} h_{20}$
$\frac{d}{dt} F_{2wy0}$
Could I ask for a hint if I am thinking correctly with this matrix? If so, how do I determine the various equations in it? Thank you in advance for any guidance.
[Sketch of tanks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Q5cu.jpg)

Comment: What is the meaning of the indices in $F_{iwy}$ ? When you say "two (inverted ?) conical tanks connected in a cascade, H1=15m , D1=5m, H2=10m, D2=7m" what are $H_i$ and $D_i$ ? Are lowercase $h_i$ and uppercase $H_i$ the same ? probably not, but in this case, what do they mean respectively, etc... You need to provide an sketch !

Comment: Is it a device like in this article : https://www.researchgate.net/publication/348674134_Level_Control_of_Coupled_Conical_Tank_System_using_Adaptive_Model_Predictive_Controller/link/60a5e38992851c43da02d9bd/download ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I just added sketch of system.

Comment: Thanks. Are $D_i$ the diameters ? $h_2$ looks equal to $F_{2wy}$ ? Besides, what is the meaning of $wy$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Yes, D stands for diameters. Wy means out. lower h is current water level in tank, upper H is tank height.  $F_{2wy} $ is second tank discharge force